# MySQL select min, max on timeline

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get min and max timestamp based on timeline? I will explain it on car parking example.

```
+---------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+
| ts                  | pos  | posidx | car   | carowner   |
+---------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+
| 2016-02-16 20:15:02 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 20:30:02 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 20:35:01 | Lev2 |      2 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 22:20:01 | Lev2 |      2 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 22:25:02 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 22:30:01 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-17 00:30:01 | Lev1 |      3 | GM    | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-17 00:35:02 | Lev1 |      3 | GM    | Mr Johnson |
```

Let's assume that pos is a parking level, posidx is a parking place number.
I need report for carowner and each his car in timeline, which should look like this:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+
| min(ts)             | max(ts)             | pos  | posidx | car   | carowner   |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+--------+-------+------------+
| 2016-02-16 20:15:02 | 2016-02-16 20:30:01 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 20:35:01 | 2016-02-16 22:20:01 | Lev2 |      2 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-16 22:25:02 | 2016-02-17 00:25:01 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |
| 2016-02-17 00:30:01 | 2016-02-17 00:35:02 | Lev1 |      3 | GM    | Mr Johnson |
```

I've tried with:

```
SELECT min(ts), max(ts), pos, posidx, car, carowner
from parking
where carowner = 'Mr Johnson'
group by pos, posidx, car
```

But because of posidx grouping it doesn't show 3rd line of above report and show its max ts in first line.

Can you help me?

Comment: How do you know which row is ENTER or EXIT? Just based on the ORDER?

Comment: There needs to be something to logically calculate that ROW3: `| 2016-02-16 22:25:02 | 2016-02-17 00:25:01 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |` is different to ROW1: `| 2016-02-16 20:15:02 | 2016-02-16 20:30:01 | Lev2 |      3 | Volvo | Mr Johnson |`

Comment: Yes. Enter is lowest ts value on each pos+posidx pair. Exit is latest ts on this pair. Parking is just an example.

Comment: @Deav If you are relying on ORDER of the rows, then Gordon's answer perfectly serves the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a grouping identifier.  One way to think of this is that it is a counter that increments when certain values change.  With that notion, you can use a variable to assign the grouping and then aggregation:

```
select min(ts), max(ts), pos, posidx, car, carowner
from (select t.*, 
             (@grp := if(@pcc = concat_ws(':', posidx, car, carowner), @grp,
                         if(@pcc := concat_ws(':', posidx, car, carowner), @grp+1, @grp+1)
                        )
             ) grp
      from t cross join
           (select @pcc := '', @grp := 0) params
      order by ts
     ) t
group by pos, posidx, car, carowner, grp;
```

Comment: it works, I don't understand yet how, but it works! Thank you.

Comment: That first @pcc := concat_ws is missing the colon. Tiny difference, but keeps it from working as expected. Do you mind fixing that? I can't edit it because it's only one character!

Comment: @AS7K . . . The first `@pcc  = concat_ws( . . . )` is *intentionally* missing the semicolon.  That is a comparison.  The second part of the logic does the assignment, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The rows 1,2,5,6 are exactly the same except the ts column. The query will display only MIN and MAX values out of these 4 rows. Logically, its impossible to tell which EXIT row corresponds to which ENTER row. To successfully retrieve your desired result, there should be another column to identify pairs of timeline rows.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: There are 2 ENTRY rows and 2 EXIT rows among the records 1,2,5,6 in the first table. However looking at the data it is not possible to tell which EXIT row corresponds to which ENTRY row because all columns are the same but timestamp. For example, Mr Johson has two Volvo cars entering and two Volvo cars exiting at Level2 pos3, we cannot tell whether row5 is an entry or an exit, even if we assume its an exit we can't tell which one is the corresponding entry record. Even if we rely or ORDER of records, what if a car ENTERED but is still parked?

Comment: Well, I agree that we have to assume that Mr Johnson only owns 1 Volvo.